# TravisCI Is it possible to be hosted on My AWS account's instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, continuous-integration, travis-ci, circleci

TravisCI Is it possible to be hosted on My AWS account's instance?
If I can't do that, I'll use "TravisCI Pro" or "CircleCI".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is possible, as Travis-ci is [open source](https://github.com/travis-ci) but it is quite difficult and consists of not one server but many different smaller servers and a few blue box workers.

Comment: I tried that, however that is too difficult because tracis-ci are consists of a complex architecture.